# Ctrl-F8 on Mac focuses on the right-side of the menu bar but doesn't do anything more than that

Tags: macos, keyboard, mac, shortcut, menu-bar

I just realized that when I press Ctrl-F8 (or Ctrl-Fn-f8), I focuses on the right side of the menu bar that controls/shows things like Wifi, battery, bluetooth, etc. However, when I press enter or spacebar, it doesn't create a dropdown where for example for Wifi, it doesn't show the dropdown where I can change to another network or something.

Comment: I get the dropdown by pressing the down arrow.

Comment: @DavidAnderson why didnt I think of that, i am a friggin idiot

Answer (score 1):

To get to the drop downs from the menu bar, press the <kbd>▼</kbd> down arrow key.

To get to the menu bar from the drop downs, press the <kbd>◀</kbd> left or <kbd>▶</kbd> right arrow key. You may need to press <kbd>◀</kbd> or <kbd>▶</kbd> more than once.

To cancel, press the <kbd>esc</kbd> key.